# How to launch multiple other python scripts all together from one and send them arguments?

Tags: python, windows

I've to launch and execute 24 independent python scripts on windows 7. I want that one script launches them all at the same time... without ruling them all (I'm not Sauron) or waiting their ends. I find os.startfile() interesting for that. But I did not succeed in sending arguments to those 24.

coincoin1.py (one of the 24 script to be launched)

```
import sys
print "hello:",sys.argv
```

Anti_Sauron_script.py (the one that will launch the 24 all together)

```
sys.argv=["send","those","arguments"] 
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\coincoin1.py")
```

**How to send arguments to those scripts and launch them all together?**

Comment: Have a look at the `multiprocessing` module. It makes this much cleaner, and is effectively that same thing (It's acutally much more efficient on linux, as it forks the current process. On windows, I think it's effectively the same as starting multiple new python processes.). If you really want to do exactly what you're describing, though, look into the `subprocess` module rather than `os.startfile`.

Answer (score 4):

You may use an indipendent process (multiprocessing.Process) and using two queues to communicate with it (multiprocessing.Queue) one for the input and the other one for the output.
Example on starting the process:

```
import multiprocessing

def processWorker(input, result):
    work = input.get()
    ## execute your command here
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
    result.put(pipe.returncode)

input  = multiprocessing.Queue()
result = multiprocessing.Queue()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = processWorker, args = (input, result))
p.start()
commandlist = ['ls -l /', 'ls -l /tmp/']
for command in commandlist:
    input.put(command)
for i in xrange(len(commandlist)):
    res = result.get(block = True)
    if not res is 0:
        print 'One command failed'
```

Then you may keep track of which command is being executed by each subprocess simply storing the command associated to a workid (the workid can be a counter incremented when the queue get filled with new work).
Usage of multiprocessing.Queue is robust since you do not need to rely on stdout/err parsing and you also avoid related limitation.
Moreover you can easily manage more subprocesses.

Then, you can also set a timeout on how long you want a get call to wait at max, eg:

```
import Queue
try:
    res = result.get(block = True, timeout = 10)
except Queue.Empty:
    print error
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html and specifically the first example in this subsection on spawning processes without waiting for them to finish http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

python_scripts = ['coincoin1.py','coincoin2.py','coincoin3.py'...]
args = ' -w hat -e ver'

procs = []
for f in python_scripts:
    procs.append(Popen(f+args, shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE))

results = []

while procs:
    results.append (procs.pop(0).communicate())

do_something_with_results(resuls)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the call function from the subprocess module (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([path, arg1, arg2...])
```

Comment: I don't think this is what has been asked... From the docs: _Run command with arguments. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute._